# How can I brighten/darken an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I guess I should be able to use GD to brighten or darken an image in PHP but don't find any info on it. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Sorry, had a bad day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `imagefilter` function provided by PHP5 and up.

`bool imagefilter ( resource $image , int $filtertype [, int $arg1 [, int $arg2 [, int $arg3 [, int $arg4 ]]]] )`

You should be using the `IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS` with a value from `-255` to `255` to brighten/darken the image.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)

Example from the manual

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('sean.png');

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, 20))
{
    echo 'Image brightness changed.';

    imagepng($im, 'sean.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else
{
    echo 'Image brightness change failed.';
}
?>
```